# Android dropping chunks of data received from peripheral device

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

I have a peripheral device that sends a string that is about 2k bytes to my Android phone. The device successfully sends it in notifications of chunks 20 bytes each. However the problem is that towards the end of the string, the data starts becoming corrupted. Meaning random chunks are being dropped . So if I had one big string like "The dog is hairy and it likes to play fetch with it's owner because it is a nice and loyal dog and super friendly". I will get "The dog is hairy and i" followed by "ause it is a nice and loyal do" followed by "g and super friendly". This is just an example and not the actual string I'm sending, but that illustrates the issue. As you can see, a chunk in the middle of the string gets dropped. Is there any reason why this could be happening? The properties of the characteristic are writeWithoutResponse and notify. The peripheral is a CSR1010 BLE chip and the phone is a Samsung S4 running Lollipop.

Comment: You did tell nothing about the receiving app. Are you programming one?

Comment: 'The device successfully sends it in notifications of chunks 20 bytes each'. How do you know that it is successfull if you receive it wrong? The sender could do it wrong or the receiver could be wrong. You have to find out which one. Are you programming both the sender and the receiver?

Comment: because it sends it to other devices successfully

Comment: You did not answer my first question. Why not?

Comment: yes I am programming one, but I am also using the application accelrator app provided by the Bluetooth SIG group

Comment: Please be more informative: which one receives bad?

Comment: both receive it badly...same results for both

Comment: Okay, so I just enabled Bluetooth HCI snoop log and use wireshark to analyze it and it looks like it drops one chunk is not received by the phone which messes everything up